# @RequestParam vs @PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

What is the difference between `@RequestParam` and `@PathVariable` while handling special characters?

`+` was accepted by `@RequestParam` as space.

In the case of `@PathVariable`, `+` was accepted as `+`.

Answer (score 563):

- `@PathVariable` is to obtain some placeholder from the URI (Spring call it an URI Template)
  — see [Spring Reference Chapter 16.3.2.2 URI Template Patterns](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates)
- `@RequestParam` is to obtain a parameter from the URI as well — see [Spring Reference Chapter 16.3.3.3 Binding request parameters to method parameters with @RequestParam](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-ann-requestparam)

If the URL `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/user/1234/invoices?date=12-05-2013` gets the invoices for user 1234 on December 5th, 2013, the controller method would look like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/{userId}/invoices", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Invoice> listUsersInvoices(
            @PathVariable("userId") int user,
            @RequestParam(value = "date", required = false) Date dateOrNull) {
  ...
}
```

Also, request parameters can be optional, and as of Spring 4.3.3 path variables [can be optional as well](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html#required--). Beware though, this might change the URL path hierarchy and introduce request mapping conflicts. For example, would `/user/invoices` provide the invoices for user `null` or details about a user with ID "invoices"?

Comment: `@PathVariable` can be used in any RequestMethod

Comment: When using Java 8, the PathVariable's name is inferred to be the argument name, so the above can be written as: @PathVariable int userId

Comment: @AlexO: this has nothing to do with java8, it works even for java 5 and Spring3.0: The point is that the code is compiled with debugging enabled.

Comment: A `null` value for `@PathVariable` will be shown as `/user//invoices` and not `/user/invoices`. I think they'll be treated differently. Maybe `/user{userId}/invoices` will have problems, I don't know.

Comment: @Ralph Correct, this works with debugging before Java 8. Since Java 8 it also works without debugging, instead using "-parameters": http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html

Comment: @Ralph Can `@PathParam` and `@RequestParam` be declared without using `@RequestMapping`?

Comment: @user3705478: i do not think so, because spring need to know that this is an request handler method. (and of course: `@PathParam`  works only if there is a placeholder in the uri template)

Comment: @Ralph I think we both meant `@PathVariable` , but since I started with `@PathParam` you also referred the same. Correct?

Comment: @user3705478: Sorry, of course, it is noit `@PathParam` but `@PathVariable`

Comment: @ralph when I did a Google search I do see `@PathParam` , but I actually don't get it.

Comment: @user3705478: `@PathParam` is an javax.ws.rs annotation. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html

Comment: If they had just called `@RequestParam` instead `@QueryVariable` (or `@QueryParam`), it'd be much more obvious when to use it vs. `@PathVariable`.

Comment: very straight forward and simple explanation. I rather not to use the backslash enable in catalina properties. It seems not working.Thanks!!

Comment: I have a question regarding this. Is it possible to pass a defined POJO object to the `@RequestParam` and still gets the same result as each `@RequestParam` you define in the controller?

Answer (score 131):

**@RequestParam** annotation used for accessing the query parameter values from the request. Look at the following request URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/springmvc/hello/101?param1=10&param2=20
```

In the above URL request, the values for param1 and param2 can be accessed as below:

```
public String getDetails(
    @RequestParam(value="param1", required=true) String param1,
        @RequestParam(value="param2", required=false) String param2){
...
}
```

The following are the list of parameters supported by the @RequestParam annotation:

- **defaultValue** – This is the default value as a fallback mechanism if request is not having the value or it is empty.
- **name** – Name of the parameter to bind
- **required** – Whether the parameter is mandatory or not. If it is true, failing to send that parameter will fail.
- **value** – This is an alias for the name attribute

**@PathVariable**

@*PathVariable* identifies the pattern that is used in the URI for the incoming request. Let’s look at the below request URL:

> http://localhost:8080/springmvc/hello/101?param1=10&param2=20

The above URL request can be written in your Spring MVC as below:

```
@RequestMapping("/hello/{id}")    public String getDetails(@PathVariable(value="id") String id,
    @RequestParam(value="param1", required=true) String param1,
    @RequestParam(value="param2", required=false) String param2){
.......
}
```

The @**PathVariable** annotation has only one attribute value for binding the request URI template. It is allowed to use the multiple @**PathVariable** annotation in the single method. But, ensure that no more than one method has the same pattern.

Also there is one more interesting annotation:
**@MatrixVariable**

> http://localhost:8080/spring_3_2/matrixvars/stocks;BT.A=276.70,+10.40,+3.91;AZN=236.00,+103.00,+3.29;SBRY=375.50,+7.60,+2.07

And the Controller method for it

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/{stocks}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String showPortfolioValues(@MatrixVariable Map<String, List<String>> matrixVars, Model model) {

    logger.info("Storing {} Values which are: {}", new Object[] { matrixVars.size(), matrixVars });

    List<List<String>> outlist = map2List(matrixVars);
    model.addAttribute("stocks", outlist);

    return "stocks";
  }
```

But you must enable:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven enableMatrixVariables="true" >
```

Comment: Will a string, such as `userName` have a type param or not? I'm leaning towards making it a variable, but it could be a param too.

Comment: ..And here is the original post :-  http://javabeat.net/spring-mvc-requestparam-pathvariable/

Comment: Can `@PathParam` and `@RequestParam` be declared without using `@RequestMapping`

Answer (score 37):

@RequestParam is use for query parameter(static values) like: http://localhost:8080/calculation/pow?base=2&ext=4

@PathVariable is use for dynamic values like : http://localhost:8080/calculation/sqrt/8

```
@RequestMapping(value="/pow", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public int pow(@RequestParam(value="base") int base1, @RequestParam(value="ext") int ext1){
    int pow = (int) Math.pow(base1, ext1);
    return pow;
}

@RequestMapping("/sqrt/{num}")
public double sqrt(@PathVariable(value="num") int num1){
    double sqrtnum=Math.sqrt(num1);
    return sqrtnum;
}
```

Answer (score 37):

1. `@RequestParam` is used to extract *query parameters* from URL:

   ```
   http://localhost:3000/api/group/test?id=4

    @GetMapping("/group/test")
    public ResponseEntity<?> test(@RequestParam Long id) {
        System.out.println("This is test");
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(id);
    }
   ```

   while `@PathVariable` is used for mapping dynamic values from the URL to a method parameter:

   ```
   http://localhost:3000/api/group/test/4

    @GetMapping("/group/test/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> test(@PathVariable Long id) {
        System.out.println("This is test");
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(id);
    }
   ```
2. `@RequestParam` could also be used in Spring MVC to bind form parameter names to method parameters in a controller. Here's an example of a simple Spring MVC controller that accepts form data submitted using the POST method.

> ```
> <form action="/submit-form" method="post">
>   <label for="name">Name:</label>
>   <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br><br>
>   
>   <label for="email">Email:</label>
>   <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br><br>
>   
>   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
> </form>
> ```

```
   @Controller
   public class FormController {

       @PostMapping("/submit-form")
       public String handleSubmitForm(
          @RequestParam(name = "name") String name,
          @RequestParam(name = "email") String email) {
             ....
             ....
             // return a view based on processing
             return "formSuccess";
       }
   }
```

3. By default, a `@PathVariable` is always considered required. If a corresponding path segment is missing, Spring will result in a 404 Not Found error.
   `@RequestParam` annotation can specify *default values* if a query parameter is not present or empty by using a `defaultValue` attribute, provided the required attribute is `false`:

   ```
   @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/name")
    String getName(@RequestParam(value = "person", defaultValue = "John") String personName) {
        return "Required element of request param";
    }
   ```

Comment: Is your argument 2 opinion based or can you provide any resource which supports that thesis?

Comment: @AnnaKlein. Here is https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch18s02.html

Comment: flawless answer @Andriy

Answer (score 1):

it may be that the application/x-www-form-urlencoded midia type convert space to **+**, and the reciever will decode the data by converting the **+** to space.check the url for more info.http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1

Answer (score 1):

```
@PathVariable - must be placed in the endpoint uri and access the query parameter value from the request
@RequestParam - must be passed as method parameter (optional based on the required property)
 http://localhost:8080/employee/call/7865467

 @RequestMapping(value=“/call/{callId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public List<Calls> getAgentCallById(
            @PathVariable(“callId") int callId,
            @RequestParam(value = “status", required = false) String callStatus) {

    }

http://localhost:8080/app/call/7865467?status=Cancelled

@RequestMapping(value=“/call/{callId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Calls> getAgentCallById(
            @PathVariable(“callId") int callId,
            @RequestParam(value = “status", required = true) String callStatus) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the annotations behave exactly in same manner.

Only 2 special characters '!' and '@' are accepted by the annotations @PathVariable and @RequestParam.

To check and confirm the behavior I have created a spring boot application that contains only 1 controller.

```
 @RestController 
public class Controller 
{
    @GetMapping("/pvar/{pdata}")
    public @ResponseBody String testPathVariable(@PathVariable(name="pdata") String pathdata)
    {
        return pathdata;
    }

    @GetMapping("/rpvar")
    public @ResponseBody String testRequestParam(@RequestParam("param") String paramdata)
    {
        return paramdata;
    }
}
```

Hitting following Requests I got the same response:

1. localhost:7000/pvar/!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{}|;':",./<>?
2. localhost:7000/rpvar?param=!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{}|;':",./<>?

!@ was received as response in both the requests

Answer (score 0):

@RequestParam:We can say it is query param like a key value pair
@PathVariable:-It is came from URI

Comment: Format code snippets to improve readability

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding

**Case 1 (@RequestParam) :**
Assume if url like key value pairs

http://localhost:8080/getStudent?aid=101

Here we will use @RequestParam annotation for getting values.

Example :

```
 @RequestMapping("/getStudent") 
 @ResponseBody 
 public String getStudentById(@RequestParam("aid") int aid) {
     String res=repo.findById(aid).toString();
     return res; 
 }
```

**Case 2 (@PathVariable):**
Assume if url like

http://localhost:8080/getStudent/101

Here we will use @PathVariable annotation for getting values.

Example:

```
 @RequestMapping("/getStudent/{aid}") 
 @ResponseBody 
 public String getStudentById(@PathVariable("aid") int aid) {
     String res=repo.findById(aid).toString();
     return res; 
 }
```