# Error 405 Method Not Allowed error, when sending DELETE to server

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest, crud

I get following response when I try to delete: 405 Method Not Allowed. 
In my logs there is written that GET is allowed, but DELETE isn't.

Java:

```
   @ResponseBody
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "/{id}")
   public void delete(@PathVariable String id) {
     speakerService.delete(id);
   }
```

Angularjs

```
  app.factory('SpeakerResource', function ($resource) {
      return $resource('rest/speaker/:speakerId',
    {
        speakerId: '@speakerId'
    },
    {
        'update': { method: 'PUT' }
    },
     {
         'delete': { method: 'DELETE', params: { 'id': 'speakerId' }}

     }
    )
 });
```

SpeakerService

```
 this.delete = function (id, callback) {

    SpeakerResource.delete({ speakerId: id }, function () {
        callback();
    });

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know your complete code, and I am not an expert in AngularJS, but it looks like your want to send a DELETE request to the URL `<hopefullySomething>/{id}` (*Path variable*). But it looks like that you send a DELETE request so some URL with an parameter id `<hopefullySomething>?id={id}` (*Request parameter*).

This question and answers explain the difference between path variable and request parameters a bit more [@RequestParam vs @PathVariable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable)

Answer (score 3):

use $http.delete(), and return data for example  status,  I just tested the following with spring and working correctly

```
@RequestMapping(value = "delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)  
     public @ResponseBody  Status deletePerson(@PathVariable("id") int id) {      
          try { 
              personService.removePerson(id); 
           return new Status(1, "person deleted Successfully !");  
          } catch (Exception e) {  
           return new Status(0, e.toString());  
          }       
     }
```

angular

```
angular.module('personService', [])

.factory('Person', ['$http',function($http) {
    return {

        deletePerson: function(id) {
            return $http.delete('/restperson/delete/'+id);
        }
    }
}]);
```

controller

```
angular.module('personController', [])

// inject the person service factory into our controller
.controller('mainController', ['$scope','$http','Person', function($scope, $http, Person) {     

    //delete
    $scope.deletePerson = function(id) {
        Person.deletePerson(id)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.message = data; 
            });
    };

}]);
```