# Two parameter in Request mapping

Tags: spring-mvc, restful-url

I have problem with request mapping with two parameters in spring MVC controller.

```
             /* Jsp page code*/

<c:url var="url_confirm" value="/admin/orderList"/>
<a href="${url_confirm}/${li.orderId}/${"confirmed"}" >Confirmed</a>
```

and in my Controller i am trying like this but i got error:-

```
@RequestMapping("/admin/orderList/${li.orderId}/${"confirmed"}")
public String changeStatus(@RequestParam("li.orderId") Integer orderId,@RequestParam("confirmed") String status) {

      // TODO
    System.out.println(orderId);
    System.out.println(status);
    return "orderList";
}
```

how i can map URL correctly with two parameter for get both value(orderId ,status) at controller ?

Comment: is ${li.orderId} resolving correctly on your jsp? Can you post your generated html code for href?

Answer (score 2):

In this case you need [@PathVariable](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html) not, [@RequestParam](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html). 
So change your mapping to,

```
@RequestMapping("/admin/orderList/{orderId}/{confirmed}")
public String changeStatus(@PathVariable("orderId") Integer orderId, @PathVariable("confirmed") String status) {

   // your code here
}
```

For more details, comparison take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable) topic.

Comment: This can be because of severl reasons. Please check your controller mapping (to be sure that you don't have any mapping, otherwise you have to add it before ```/admin/*```). Also check your MVC configurations. If possible edit your question with more details, so the problem can be catched.

Comment: all other configuration are ok. my other controller are work fine.

Comment: Looks like you still have ``` @RequestMapping("/admin/orderList/${li.orderId}/${confirmed}")``` . Change it to ``` @RequestMapping("/admin/orderList/{orderId}/{confirmed}")```

Comment: As you can see in docs and discussions, this is the correct way to build mapping. Sorry but with provided code it is not possible to guess the problem.