# Receive URL parameter on a Spring controller from an Angular application

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

In my spring controller, I have this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
@ResponseBody
public void deleteUser(@RequestParam(value = "id") long id) throws Exception {
    users.delete(id); // It works on tests
}
```

Here I want to delete the passed user in the URL (from his ID).

In my AngularJS application, I have this module:

```
angular.module('app')
    .factory('DeleteUserService', function($resource) {
        return $resource('/users/:id', {id:'@id'}, {
            deleteUser: {
                method:'DELETE',
                headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I call the module from my user administration page, with this:

```
DeleteUserService.deleteUser({id:$scope.id}, function() { //$scope.id = 15
    console.log('Correctly deleted!');
});
```

The problem is that I get a 400 Bad Request error: `DELETE http://localhost:8080/users/15` `[HTTP/1.1 400 Required long parameter 'id' is not present 2ms]`

I do not understand why my controller does not see the param :/

Could you help me finding the problem ?

Thanks, do not hesitate if you need additional code.

Comment: Use `@PathVariable` not `@RequestParam`. Here's an answer that explains the difference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [@PathVariable](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html) instead `@RequestParam` in that case.

Comment: I think it's '@PathVariable', not '@PathParam'.

Comment: @PathParam is Jax-rs specific, OP does not mention jax-rs, only spring!

Comment: PathVariable works perfectly. PathParam also exists but is different. Thanks :)