# diffrence between @RequestParam and @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, request-mapping

Line1:

```
public ModelAndView viewCustomerDetails(@RequestParam("custId") Integer customerId, @RequestParam("categoryName") String categoryName, HttpServletRequest request) throws BusinessException{
```

Line2:

```
public ModelAndView viewCustomerDetails(@RequestMapping("custId") Integer customerId, @RequestMapping("categoryName") String categoryName, HttpServletRequest request) throws BusinessException{
```

i am going thorough my project code and having some confusion in `@RequestParam` and `@RequestMapping` some times i found `@RequestParam` and some times `@RequestMapping`. in my understanding both will assign the value of `custId` to `customerId` data member.

some part of my jsp file:

```
<form:input mandatory="true" id="CustNameTxt" path="custName" cssClass="txtfield controlWidth" readonly="false" />
```

for better understanding of my problem i have done editting in Line2

Comment: `@RequestParam` map a single request parameter, `@RequestMapping` should be used to map a web resource to the handler class or method not   to map parameters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You compare apples with pears. Both annotations have nothing in common except that this are Spring MVC annotations, and your usage of `@RequestMapping("categoryName")` is *wrong*!

- `@RequestMapping` is an class or method annotation to map the request url to the java method.
- `@RequestParam` is a (Method) field annotation to to bind a request parameter to an method parameter

---

*Maybe you mashed `@RequestMapping` with `@PathVariable`, and your question is about the difference of `@RequestParam` and `@PathVariable` - then have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13718502/280244).*

Comment: thanks @Ralph for dropping ur valuable comment yah ´@RequestMapping("categoryName")´ was wrong. i've already mentioned it in my problem that i've editted Line2 to explain my problem in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

`@RequestMapping` maps the request to resource . It is used on methods not in their parameters .From [SpringByExample](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-spring-mvc-form-annotation-config-webapp-code-example.html)

> The @Controller indicates the class is a Spring MVC controller
>   stereotype which is automatically registered by context:component-scan
>   in the web-application-context.xml. The @RequestMapping annotation on
>   the methods use the value attribute to map the method to a path. The
>   method attribute is used to indicate the HTTP request type (ex: GET,
>   POST, DELETE).

`@RequestParam` binds the parameters from resource URL to the arguments in the method.