# Spring Boot: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://localhost:8080/error'

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-boot

Everytime I used ajax for posting, I'm getting this error but the passing of data works successfully. Some said that it is because of my return statement. I also don't have any mapping for /error. This is one of my work that causes this error.

AJAX:

```
$.ajax
({
type: 'post',
url: '/SaveDependent',
data: 
{
    dependent_id: 0,
    reference_no: referenceNo,
    dependent_name: dNameValue[i],
    dependent_dob: dDobValue[i],
    dependent_gender: dGenderValue[i],
    dependent_occupation: dOccupationValue[i],
    dependent_relationship: dRelationshipValue[i],
    dependent_beneficiary: dBeneficiaryValue[i]
},
success: function (response) 
{
    alert("success");
},
});
```

CONTROLLER:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/SaveDependent", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveDependent(ClientApplicationDependent clientApplicationDependent) {
        clientApplicationDependentService.saveOrUpdate(clientApplicationDependent);
        return "success";
}
```

SERVICE:

```
public interface ClientApplicationDependentService {
    public void saveOrUpdate(ClientApplicationDependent clientApplicationDependent);
}
```

SERVICE IMPL:

```
@Override
public void saveOrUpdate(ClientApplicationDependent clientApplicationDependent) {
    clientApplicationDependentRepository.save(clientApplicationDependent);
}
```

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32837964/ambiguous-handler-methods-for-http-path][1]

Comment: Are you using @RestController or @Controller?

Comment: @Rentius2407 Controller

Comment: Is success a page? i.e. success.html or is it the response body? If you want it as response body, change your method to include `@ResponseBody` in the response. `public @ResponseBody String saveDependent(ClientApplicationDependent clientApplicationDependent)`