# How Spring controller handles parameter implicitly?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am a newbie on Spring framework and maybe this is an easy question.

I have a link as follows and attempt Spring controller handles the value"201610061023" of this link.However,my code did not work.

I know this value can be attached as a parameter or pathvariable in path but I just curious can I pass this value implicitly?

Thank you very much.

```
<a href="./Order" name="test">201610061023</a>

@RequestMapping(value = "/Order")
public String requestHandlingMethod(@ModelAttribute("test") String name, HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "nextpage";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring will not handle the title of the link simply because the title of the link will not be sent by the browser. To send it you can either:

1. add the value as parameter: `<a href="./Order?id=201610061023" name="test">201610061023</a>`
2. add the value as path variable: `<a href="./Order/201610061023" name="test">201610061023</a>`
3. add a JavaScript that will copy the title onClick into the `href` or send the generated URL with `document.location`. This can be automated, but it's pretty uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

Your a-tag is wrong, you **need to submit the id**, there is no implicit way to submit the link-text *(except a lot of java script code)*!

```
 <a href="./Order/201610061023" name="test">201610061023</a>


@RequestMapping(value = "/Order/{orderId}")
public String requestHandlingMethod(@PathVariable("orderId") long orderId, @ModelAttribute("test") String name, HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "nextpage";
}
```

or

```
 <a href="./Order?orderId=201610061023" name="test">201610061023</a>


@RequestMapping(value = "/Order")
public String requestHandlingMethod(@RequestParam("orderId") long orderId, @ModelAttribute("test") String name, HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "nextpage";
}
```

See [@RequestParam vs @PathVariable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable) for the difference between this two approaches

Comment: Thank you for help.I know these two ways and in this case I want to find an implicit way of passing parameter.