# how can i store the value of path variable and use it in my controller method?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

When i launch the below url

```
http://localhost:8090/QuickStartConsulting/quickstart/email?key=6226f7cbe59e99a90b5cef6f94f966fd
```

The following controller method is invoked

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/quickstart/email")

    public String viewQuickStartEmailForm(@ModelAttribute(value = "quickbean") 
    QuickStartBean quickbean,BindingResult result,Model model) {

        try {   

            //System.out.println(quickbean.getKey());           
email=quickbean.getEmail();
model.addAttribute("email", email);

model.addAttribute("quickstartdatabean",new QuickStartBean() );


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return "quickstart/emaillogin";
    }
```

Here is my emaillogin jsp page

```
    <form:form id="requestForm" method="GET" modelAttribute="quickbean" ACTION="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/quickstart/email" >
                   <form:hidden path="key" />                                      
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td><span><img src="<c:url value="/views/images/youremailid.png"/>"> </img></span></td>
                            <td>
                                <form:input type="text" style="width: 300px;" id="name" path="email" title="xyz@email.com"/>

                        </td></tr>


                        <tr>
                        <td>

                         <input type="image" id="invite_btn" src="<c:url value="/views/images/submit.png"/>"  title="create invite" width="170" height="32"/> 

                        </td>
                        </tr>


                    </table>



                </form:form>
```

**How can i store the value of path variable 'key' and use it in my controller method?** the emaillogin page is the first page and is not redirected from any other jsp page.

Comment: 'key' is no path variable, it is a request parameter! see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable/13718502#13718502

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `@RequestParam` annotation

```
public String viewQuickStartEmailForm(@RequestParam("key") String key, ....) {...}
```

*Btw: @See [@RequestParam vs @PathVariable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable/13718502#13718502) for details and difference between request params and path variables*

Comment: when i use the @RequestParam("key") String key i am getting a exception

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'quickbean' available as request attribute

Comment: `public String viewQuickStartEmailForm(@RequestParam("key") String key, @ModelAttribute(value = "quickbean") 
    QuickStartBean quickbean,BindingResult result,Model model)` -- but you should clean up that parameter mess

Comment: when i am putting RequestParam("key") before ModelAttribute.... I am not able to use quickbean to get form values

Comment: than put at at the end (but not between quickbeen and binding result)

Answer (score 0):

First define pathVariables as follows:

```
public String viewQuickStartEmailForm(@PathVariable Map pathVariables,..)
```

You can get the values by using below code snippet:

```
    if (pathVariables != null) {
        if (pathVariables.containsKey("fieldName") &&
                !"undefined".equals(
                    (String)pathVariables.get("fieldName")) &&
                !"null".equals(
                    (String)pathVariables.get("fieldName"))) {
            params.setFieldName((String)pathVariables.get("fieldName"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: when i use the code it says the request sent was syntactically in correct

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between @PathVariable and @RequestParam. For example :

@RequestParam used for accessing the values of the query parameters.

URL : http://localhost:8081/Test/card?cardId=1012111

@RequestMapping("/card")
public String getCard(@RequestParam(value="cardId", required=true) String cardId){

```
System.out.println("print the value of the cardId : "+cardId)
```

.......
}

where as @PathVariable used for accessing the values from the URI template.

URL : http://localhost:8081/Test/card/1012111

@RequestMapping("/card/{cardId}")
public String updateCard(@PathVariable(value="cardId") String cardId){

```
System.out.println("print the value of the cardId : "+cardId)
```

.......
}

So you can correct your code and use any one of the above mentioned approach rather then mixing both of them.