# How do I pass my object between 2 requests? Where server is stateless?

Tags: spring, object, request

How do I pass my object between 2 requests? Where server is stateless, hence session cannot be used. Request object access is not there in controller class.Left with caching or using cookies, but is that a good way? since cookies do not allow objects and i will have to copy strings individually, which can make cookies huge.

I haven't explored caching much although.

Any guidance please?

Framework : Spring 3

Comment: An other way to pass information form one request to an other one is to put the information in the request parameters, by adding them to (each) link that is returned as response for the first request.

Comment: I am not sure how these request parameters will reach my spring controller..any idea?

Comment: Have you considered to use Model? or requests interceptors?

Comment: @Dish spring controller methods obtain request parameter for example by `@RequestParam` or `@PathVariable` annotation (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13718502/280244) or by CommandObject /  Model