# Getting null with @pathparam and @requestmapping

Tags: spring-boot

I am using spring-boot 1.4.3.RELEASE for creating web services, whereas, while giving the request with `http://localhost:7211/person/get/ram`, I am getting null for the id property

```
@RequestMapping(value="/person/get/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Person getPersonById(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        return personService.getPersonById(id);
    }
```

Can you please suggest me, is there anything I missed.

Comment: "@PathParam" is JAX-RS annotation and used in implementation like Jersey. Spring equivalent annotation is "@PathVariable".

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The annotation to get path variable is **@PathVariable**. It looks like you have used @PathParam instead which is incorrect.

Check this out for more details:

[requestparam-vs-pathvariable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13718502/3494368)

Comment: you're welcome.. can you please select answer as 'correct'. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

As above answers already mentioned **@PathVariable should be used**, I thought to clear the **confusion between @PathVariable & @PathParam**.

*Most people get confused on this part because **Spring and other rest implementation like Jersey use sightly different annotations for the same thing**.*

**`@QueryParam` in Jersey** is **`@RequestParam` in Spring Rest API**.

**`@PathParam` in Jersey** is **`@PathVariable` in Spring Rest API**.

Answer (score 3):

Use @PathVariable annotation instead of @PathParam.

Answer (score 1):

`id` should be `Long` instead of `String` at `@PathVariable`. If so, then ...

```
@RequestMapping(value="/person/get/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody Person getPersonById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    return personService.getPersonById(id);
}
```