# Spring REST error 500

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, rest

I am implementing REST service using Spring. When i call delete function the request doesn't reach controller and from JS i receive error: angular.js:12587 DELETE http://localhost:8080/Guard_Server/restapi/sites?siteId=5 500 (Internal Server Error)

my controller function looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="sites", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
boolean deleteSite(@PathVariable("siteId") int site_id, HttpServletResponse res){
    .......
}
```

And AngularJS function is:

```
$scope.deleteSite=function(){
            if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Site?")){
                var site={};
                site.siteId=sites[$scope.selectedSite].id;
                console.log(site);
                siteFactory.delete(site).$promise.then(function(result){
                    ...
                }
                ,error_on_execute);
            }
        }
```

with factory:

```
serverApp.factory('referentFactory',['$resource',function ($resource){
   return $resource("http://localhost:8080/Guard_Server/restapi/referents",null,{ 'update': {method: 'PUT'} });
}]);
```

Comment: why don't add `@ResponseBody` to `deleteSite` function and why this function return primitive not object. also `$resource` url not match with `RequestMapping`

Comment: URL Matches as for ControllerClass stands `@RestController
@RequestMapping("/restapi/")`, other methods work, so the problem is not URL. `@RequestBody` instead of `@PathVariable` doesn't resolve the problem,already tried

Comment: if use `@RequestMapping(value="sites", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
 boolean deleteSite(@RequestBody int siteId, HttpServletResponse res)` the error changes to 400 BAD Request

Comment: as i see in your url you should use `@RequestParam`

Comment: `@RequestParam` worked! but what is the difference between `@RequestPath` and `@RequestParam`?

Comment: @Hadi If you will post this as solutio I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see in the url

**`http://localhost:8080/Guard_Server/restapi/sites?siteId=5`**

you should use `@RequestParam` instead of `@PathVariable`.

`@RequestParam` use for access query parameter and `@PathVariable` is part of url.

**@RequestParam**:

```
   http://localhost:8080/Guard_Server/restapi/sites?siteId=5
```

**@PathVariable**

```
   http://localhost:8080/Guard_Server/restapi/sites/siteId/5
```

[see this for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable)