# springmvc can get data from post json,but get null from post key-value pair,why?

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, post

If I `post` json in jquery,and then can get data in springmvc with `@RequestBody`

```
$.ajax({
        url:"menu_selectByName",
        method:"post",
        data:JSON.stringify({menuName:"index"}),
        contentType:"application/json",
        success:function(res){
            $scope.content = res;
        }}
)

@RequestMapping(value = "/menu_selectByName") 
@ResponseBody
public Menu selectByName(@RequestBody String json){
    //json = "{"menuName":"index"}"
    System.out.println(json):

    //other operations
}
```

but if I post key-value pair with `x-www-form-urlencoded`,then springmvc can not get datas

```
$.ajax({
        url:"menu_selectByName",
        method:"post",
        data:{menuName:"index"},
        contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        success:function(res){
            $scope.content = res;
        }}
)

@RequestMapping(value = "/menu_selectByName")
@ResponseBody
public Menu selectByName(String menuName){
    //menuName = null
    System.out.println(menuName);
    return  menuService.selectByName(menuName);
}
```

if i write like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/menu_selectByName")
@ResponseBody
public Menu selectByName(@RequestParam("menuName") String menuName){
    //menuName = null
    System.out.println(menuName);
    return  menuService.selectByName(menuName);
}
```

it will report

```
  HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request

  Type:Status Report

  Message:Required String parameter 'menuName' is not present

  Description:The server cannot or will not process the request due to 
something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request 
syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).
```

where did I make a mistake?

Comment: It's been a while since I did some spring, but I vaguely remember you may have to do something in your parameters like `selectByName(@RequestParam('menuName') String menuName)` so it knows which param to map to that variable.  Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable

Comment: I had tried to add  `@RequestParam("menuName")`, but if I do this,it will report `http status 400 - bad request`,message is `Required String parameter 'menuName' is not present`