# Spring Boot MockMvc not working test with @PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-boot

With Spring Boot, I want to test my @RestController, everything is good except when I try to test a request mapping with @PathParam.

This involve the interface (in this case TestController) holding the annotation for request mapping ! If I remove the interface all is good ... Seemes to be an issue ...

My Controller :

```
public interface TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/bar/{foo}/baz", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String test(@PathVariable("foo") String foo);


    @RestController
    class TestControllerImpl implements TestController {

        @Override
        public String test(String foo) {
            return foo;
        }
    }

}
```

My Tests :

```
@Test
public void notworkingtest() throws Exception {

    //THIS TEST SHOULD WORK, BUT DON'T ...

    final MockMvc mockMvc = ...

    mockMvc.perform(get("/bar/{foo}/baz", "foovalue") // Or get("/bar/foovalue/baz")
            .contentType("text/plain"))
            .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful())
            .andExpect(content().string("foovalue"));

}

@Test
public void strangeworkingtest() throws Exception {

    //THIS TEST WORKS, BUT WHY ?!?

    final MockMvc mockMvc = ...

    mockMvc.perform(get("/bar/{foo}/baz", "WhatEverValue")
            .param("foo", "foovalue") // This param should be useless ...
            .contentType("text/plain"))
            .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful())
            .andExpect(content().string("foovalue"));

}
```

The second test is working when I had .param("foo","foovalue) and keep the get("/bar/{foo}/baz", "WhatEverValue") ...

If I remove the interface of the Controller it works ...

Can someone explain to me ?

Thx

Comment: You could replace get("/test/{foo})" with get("/test/foovalue") without the param.

Comment: `.param("foo", "foovalue")` sets the value

Comment: @sergiu Already try .. does the same behavior ...

Comment: @Sam : Yes but why I do need it, it shoudl be set by the uri ?

Comment: actually that param is not useless as it overrides the first one

Comment: @Oziris just ran your test and `notworkingtest` does pass.

Comment: @Sam, strange I use spring boot 1.5.6 ... and have some security and filter ... , could be a security matter ? does the strangeworkingtest() works too ?

Comment: @Sam, without security and filter ... the test doesn't pass at home ...(i have spring test 4.3.10.RELEASE)

Comment: @sergiu, yes not useless, but should be .., I had it to make the test working ... but why I need it ?

Comment: of course if you have security setup you need to authenticate during your get request

Comment: Please include the error from assert in the description

Comment: I remove all specific configuration, I rewrote my real pb ... In fact it involves interface for request mapping, see my update

Comment: You need the `@PathVariable` in your actual implementation and not the interface. imho defining an interface for a controller when using annotations to define the controller is pretty much useless.

Answer (score 2):

Here is two ways:

1. Change the URL for your endpoint:

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)

   mockMvc.perform(get("/test")
               .param("foo", "Value"))
               .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful())
               .andExpect(content().string("foovalue"));
   ```
2. Use proper URL to call your endpoint:

   ```
   mockMvc.perform(get("/user/1568/delete"))
       .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful())
       .andExpect(content().string("foovalue"));
   ```

Comment: nope .. get a 404

Comment: @Oziriz, Update your annotation with next :@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)

Comment: not what I want ... my uri is more complexe this is just an example. like : /user/1568/delete, where 1568 is an id

Comment: @Oziris, So just use a proper URL for your request:
mockMvc.perform(get(" /user/1568/delete"))
            .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful())
            .andExpect(content().string("foovalue"));

You can make some URL builder which will do it for you.

Comment: already try ... just the same behavior ...

Comment: get("/test/{foo}", "foovalue") and get("/test/foovalue") does the same ...

Comment: @Oziris, 404 for all cases?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153441/discussion-between-oziris-and-speise).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/test/{foo}?foo=" + "foovalue")
        .contentType("text/plain"))
        .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful())
        .andExpect(content().string("foovalue"));
```

Answer (score 0):

PathVariable differs from requestParam as pathVariable is part of URL.
that's why `.param("foo", "foovalue")` is not overriding your pathVariable as the latter one is setting a requestParam.

see [@RequestParam vs @PathVariable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable)