# What is the difference between @RequestParam and @PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, controller

My understanding is request parameters is the required id for the method to pass while path variable says this variable should be found in the request process

```
   @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_COACH')")

    @PostMapping(value = "/courses/{courseId}/background/update")

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)

    @ResponseBody

    public CourseLiteInfo updateBackground(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,

                                           @PathVariable(value = "courseId") Long courseId) throws IOException {



        return new CourseLiteInfo(courseService.updateBackground(courseId, file));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Hi**,

@RequestParam is a parameter binded as a query param. This parameter can be optional to apply a filter, for example.

```
google.com?query=param
```

@PathVariable is a parameter binded as a param in the url. This parameter is required to be informed.

```
yourapp.com/users/pathparam
```

Answer (score 0):

RequestParam maps to a named URL parameter on the URL.

PathVariable is a part of the URL path that can be changed but still maps to the same controller mapping

For e.g.

http://somedomain.com/account/123/details?type=sometype

Here 123 would be a PathVariable that can be named anything we want and sometype is the value of a RequestParam which has to be name type.

Answer (score 0):

@**QueryParam** is used to access key/value pairs in the query string of the URL (the part after the ?). For example in the url http://stackoverflow.com/questions?q=query, you can use @QueryParam("q") to get the value of q.

@**PathParam** is used to match a part of the URL as a parameter. For example in an url of the form http://stackoverflow.com/questions/{questionid}, you can use @PathParam("questionid") to get the id of a question

Comment: So  QueryParam is equal to  RequestParam  and PathVariable is PathParam ?

Comment: Yes, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable