# Spring Thymeleaf - How to map to a URL that requires an ID that is passed from HTML to the controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapping, thymeleaf

In my application the user clicks a link to edit an exam of their choice.

When they click the link it should open the editExam.html and the URL contains the ID of the exam they selected.

When I click the link the URL is correct (it contains the exam ID) however it doesn't display the editExam.html page it just displays my main page (the default localhost page)

[image]

allSubjects.html (the page where the user selects which exam to edit)

```
    <h4> exams:</h4>
<div th:each="exam : ${subject.exam}"> 
<h4 th:text="${exam.examTitle}"/>
    <a th:href="@{/editExam.html(id=${exam.examId})}">Edit Exam</a>
```

editExam.html (this is the page I can't display)

```
<form action="#"th:action="@{/editExam.html{examId}}"  th:object="${exam}" method="put">


    <table>
        <tr>
        <td> Exam Title:</td>
         <td><input type="text" th:field="*{examTitle}" th:text="${exam.examTitle}"/></td>
    <!--    <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('examTitlee')}" th:errors="*{examTitle}">error message</td>  --> 
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <td> Exam grade worth </td>
            <td><input th:field="*{examGradeWorth}" /></td>
        <!--    <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('examGradeWorth')}" th:errors="*{examGradeWorth}">error message</td> -->
            </tr>  
            <tr>
                <td>examGradeAchieved</td>
                <td><input th:field="*{examGradeAchieved}"/></td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button type="submit">Submit post</button></td>
                </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

My controller:

```
//Update an exam
@RequestMapping(value = "/editExam.html{examId}", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT})
public String editExam(@ModelAttribute("exam") @PathVariable(value = "examId")Long examId, @RequestBody Exam exam,Model model, BindingResult result) {

            examRepository.findOne(examId);
            model.addAttribute("examTitle", exam.getExamTitle());
            model.addAttribute("examGradeWorth", exam.getExamGradeWorth());
            model.addAttribute("examGradeAchieved", exam.getExamGradeAchieved());


        exam.setExamTitle(exam.getExamTitle());
         exam.setExamGradeWorth(exam.getExamGradeWorth());
         exam.setExamGradeAchieved(exam.getExamGradeAchieved());

          examRepository.save(exam);

    return "editExam";
}
```

This code was displaying the editExam page before I added "RequestMethod.POST" to the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
<a th:href="@{/editExam.html(id=${exam.examId})}">Edit Exam</a>
```

to

```
<a th:href="@{/exam/{id}(id=${exam.examId})}">Edit Exam</a>
```

and in your Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editExam.html{examId}", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT})
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/exam/{examId}", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I implemented that but unfortunately it still didn't work. I am going to try display the editExam.html with a separate method with a get request and see how I get on.

Comment: [This project](https://github.com/st-tu-dresden/videoshop) could help you if you are stuck. The catalog with discs is almost the same as your subjects and exams.

Answer (score 1):

This url does not look correct. It should be `/editExam.html?id=1`, without a `/`.

I noticed that you are mixing request params and path variables. In your controller you expect `@PathVariable(value = "examId")` but in the view you are specifying request parameter instead of path variable.

Check this post: [@RequestParam vs @PathVariable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable)