# Spring checkbox parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a problem with checkbox. I have such jsp page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>All Photos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/photos/deletePhotos">
    <c:forEach var="photo" items="${photoList}">
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="id" value="${photo.key}">${photo.key}</p>
        <img src="/photos/photo/${photo.key}" width="300" height="200">
        <br/><br/>
    </c:forEach>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

and such controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/deletePhotos")
    public ModelAndView deleteSomePhotos(@PathVariable(name = "id", required = false) long[] id) {
        System.out.println(id);
        return new ModelAndView("all", "photoList", photos);
    }
```

problem is id==null, no matter checked checkbox or not. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@PathVariable` is for path variable, like `@RuquestMapping("/deletePhotos/{id}")`. 
Use `@RequestParam` instead of @PathVariable.

Refer here : [@RequestParam vs @PathVariable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable)