# pass parameter through <a href=""> and get it to spring mvc controller

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to pass `clusterId=1` as parameter from 
`<a href="http://192.168.11.134:8080/UniconnectConfigurationWeb/nodes?clusterId=1">` and get it into spring mvc controller through `@PathParam("clusterId")Integer clusterId`. But I'm getting 404 error.

Guide me how to pass parameter through anchor tag and how to hit controller and get the parameter value.
I am sharing my code below,

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/nodes?clusterId={clusterId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public ModelAndView nodes(@RequestParam("clusterId")Integer clusterId,HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) {
         System.out.println(clusterId);
       return dashboard;
      }
    }
<c:url var="myURL" value="http://192.168.11.134:8080/UniconnectConfigurationWeb/nodes">
    <c:param name="clusterId" value="1"/>
</c:url>
```

Comment: as you have the `@RequestParam` you do not need the `@RequestMapping` to include `?clusterId={clusterId}` - change to `@RequestMapping(value = "/nodes"..`

Comment: Also try by typing in the URL in a browser

Comment: see https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-requestmapping-example/ [1.2.5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are using clusterId as Request Parameter , and passing from client side to server side. but in your server side code you are used  `?clusterId={clusterId}` in Request Mapping annotation and you are trying to receive that request parameter with `@RequestParam` Annotation. here `@RequestParam` is enough for receiving Request Parameter. so, no need to use this ?clusterId={clusterId}`,  this is not correct way of writing server side URL.

it may helps you for better understanding [@RequestParam vs @PathVariable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable)