# MissingServelException SpringBoot

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, path-variables

I gets an error in Spring Boot , It say that I don't send `paramSelect` but it is false, I send paramSelect.

I send

```
 public filterResult(paramSelect: string, filterDateStart: string, filterDateEnd: string): Observable<any> {
  filterDateStart = filterDateStart.replace(/\//g, '-');
  filterDateEnd = filterDateEnd.replace(/\//g, '-');

const url = 'http://localhost:8080/filterResult/' + paramSelect + '/' + filterDateStart + '/' + filterDateEnd;
return this.http.get<any>(url);
```

Html ERROR->

```
zone.js:2969 GET http://localhost:8080/filterResult/EDU/04-07-2018/05-07-2018 400 ()
```

In my SpringBoot ->

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/filterResult/{paramSelect}/{dateStart}/{dateEnd}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public List filterResult(@RequestParam("paramSelect") String  paramSelect , @RequestParam("dateStart") String dateStart , @RequestParam("dateEnd") String dateEnd) {
    System.out.println("llego");
    List<Parameter> list = pgService.filterResult(paramSelect, dateStart, dateEnd);
    return list;
}
```

I get an error:

```
Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'paramSelect' is not present
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@RequestParam vs @PathVariable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change to use [@PathVariable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable) instead of `@RequestParam` for **path** variables:

```
 public List filterResult(@PathVariable("paramSelect") String  paramSelect , @PathVariable("dateStart") String dateStart , @PathVariable("dateEnd") String dateEnd) {
```