# My PathVariables does not work

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

Hello I would like to write a Get method with Spring Rest but my code is not working code is below;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "userRight/hasRightForOperation", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> hasRightForOperation(@PathVariable(value = "loginName") String loginName,
            @PathVariable(value = "vendorId") String vendorId,
            @PathVariable(value = "accessRightCode") String accessRightCode) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(hasRightForOperation(loginName, vendorId, accessRightCode), HttpStatus.OK);
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Where you have a path variable in your URL mapping?

Comment: I think you have to use @RequestParam

Comment: I think you want to use a parameter. Just remove the `@PathVariable(...)` annotation. Else, please show the URL you are sending a GET request to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "userRight/hasRightForOperation", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> hasRightForOperation(@PathVariable(value = "loginName") String loginName,
        @PathVariable(value = "vendorId") String vendorId,
        @PathVariable(value = "accessRightCode") String accessRightCode) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(hasRightForOperation(loginName, vendorId, accessRightCode), HttpStatus.OK);
```

You are using @PathVariable but there is no param to your url mapping. 
You can fix like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "userRight/hasRightForOperation/{loginName}/{vendorId}/{accessRightCode}", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> hasRightForOperation(@PathVariable(value = "loginName") String loginName,
        @PathVariable(value = "vendorId") String vendorId,
        @PathVariable(value = "accessRightCode") String accessRightCode) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(hasRightForOperation(loginName, vendorId, accessRightCode), HttpStatus.OK);
```

You can change order of url mapping params. So if you dont wants in url mapping, you can get params with @RequestParam tags.

```
@GetMapping(value = "userRight/hasRightForOperation", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> hasRightForOperation(@RequestParam("loginName") String loginName,
                                              @RequestParam("vendorId") String vendorId,
                                              @RequestParam("accessRightCode") String accessRightCode) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(hasRightForOperation(loginName, vendorId, accessRightCode), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: I'm glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

You have to receive path variables in URL so for doing that add all params like below.

Change

```
@RequestMapping(value = "userRight/hasRightForOperation", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "userRight/hasRightForOperation/{loginName}/{vendorId}/{accessRightCode}", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

I will recommend you to use `@RequestParam` for this.

See this :  [@RequestParam vs @PathVariable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable)

Comment: Thank you but what about vendorId and AccessRightCode do ı need to change them too according to that code

Comment: yes updated the answer accordingly...make sure while hitting the controller the parameters should be in same sequence.

Comment: please accept and upvote the answer if it helped you.