# Send PathVariable @PostMapping in postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want send path variable in post mapping, in postman software.I select post mapping body and then how to do? I checked with [@RequestParam vs @PathVariable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable) example,all answers for get method, But I need answer for post method.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/customers") 
public class CustomerController {

@PostMapping("/{code}")
    public String postRequest(@PathVariable String code,@RequestBody CustomerDTO dto){
         System.out.println(dto);
         System.out.println(code);
         return "Something";
    }
}
```

Comment: The `PathVariable` is part of the URL

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable

Comment: you can use uri in postman like this "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/customers//{code}" select post dropdown and send the request.

Comment: No we can't send values through url, in post mapping, in another words we can't edit url in post method

Comment: can you show me your hitting uri approach from postman?

Comment: HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type

Type Status Report

Description The origin server is refusing to service the request because the payload is in a format not supported by this method on the target resource.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@RequestParam vs @PathVariable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

select post -> add the url -> select body -> choose raw -> select JSON(application/json) -> add your json data -> click send

Comment: what you have shown in the picture is POST body, but the question is asking about Path variable. Your answer is not relevant to the actual question asked.

Comment: this does not answer the path variable question.

Answer (score 47):

the easy way to put a path variable in Postman is your case is "/:code"

[image: check link to see how to add path variables in Postman]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Some of us can't view images or follow links. Could you post the image instead? And perhaps lengthen your explanation a bit?

Comment: I was using 7.36.3

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, enjoy the upvote!

Answer (score 3):

You can refer official documentation :

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/requests

Please go to charpter URL .

Some API endpoints use path variables. You can work with those in Postman. Below is an example of a URL with a path variable:

https://api.library.com/:entity/

To edit the path variable, click on Params to see it already entered as the key. Update the value as needed. For example, :entity can be “user” in this specific case. Postman also gives you suggestions to autocomplete the URL.