# Best approach to create rest url to call external api in Java and SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, api, spring-boot, endpoint

I'm working in a SpringBoot project where I'm developing a rest endpoint which will receive a few parameters and based on these parameters I will create a uri and I'll call another external endpoint to retrieve an image.

Right now I have a rest controller with the following endpoint:

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}/{param4}", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
    public byte[] getImageryBaseMap(@PathVariable("param1") Long param1, @PathVariable("param2") Long param2,
                                    @PathVariable("param3") Long param3, @PathVariable("param4") Long param4)
    throws IOException{
        //calls my service
        return myService.getMyMethod(param1, param2, param3, param4);
    }
```

On myService class I make the call to an external endpoint.

```
 public byte[] retrieveImageryBaseMap(Long param1,  Long param2, Long param3, Long param4){
        String url = "https://host-name:6443/external/Image/export?bbox="+ param1 +"%" + param2+ "+%"+ param3 + "%" + param4 +"&format=png&f=image";

       // here I call the external api endpoint to retrieve an image
        byte[] image = getImage(url);
        return image;
    }
```

My questions would be:

1) What is the best approach/practices to manage creating the url above? I basically hardcoded almost all the url above just replacing the values by the parameters coming from the method **retrieveImageryBaseMap** . Would like to know if there's a better approach for that or if it's ok.

2)I also hardcoded the host name and the port in the url  `String url = "https://host-name:6443/external/Image/export?bbox="+ param1 +"%" + param2+ "+%"+ param3 + "%" + param4 +"&format=png&f=image";` Right now I'm just testing this using the dev host-name, but in production the host name and port will be different. So also would like to ask the best approach/practice to manage the host name in the url? Should I hardcoded like that or use a different approach?

Guys much appreciate any help, I'm working by myself and unfortunately don't have a mentor to ask those sort of questions and got stuck here.

Cheers!

Comment: One little question why you are passing params through PathVariable?

Comment: You can reed this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable

Comment: Yes, PathVariable

Comment: If those parameters are coming from internet clients you _really_ want to be validating them before constructing a URL out of them.

Comment: @AndyBrown it's a restfull endpoint. Client will send geographic coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UriComponentBuilder for such purposes it’s very flexible

Here is an example :

```
String URI = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
      .scheme("https").host("host-name").port(6443).pathSegment("external”,”Image”,”export”)
      .queryParam(“paramName1”, value1)
      .queryParam(“paramName2”,value2)
      .build(). toUriString();
```

Here is url for documentation 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html

Comment: Thanks @Mykhailo! I'll check it out! Much appreciated it!

Comment: Added example . Thanks

Comment: @RafaelPaz In addition to this, I would highly recommend you to store the base url `https://host-name:6443/external/Image/` in application.properties file instead of hardcoding in the code

Comment: Thanks for the tip @KunalPuri! Will do that! Much appreciate your help!

Comment: Thanks again @MykhailoMoskura helped a lot mate! :)