# How to pass a variable from html select as a PathVariable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, jstl

I have a form like this:

```
<form action="/list/${tableName}" method="post">
<p>
<select name="tableName">
<option value="employees">Employees</option>
<option value="contracts">Contracts</option>
</select>
</p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and on the controller side:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/list/{tableName}", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
    public String getTables(Model m, @PathVariable("tableName") String tableName) {
...
//findAll here
...
return "home";
}
```

It writes "not found"
P.S.: what is now @PathVariable used to be @RequestParam as I'm using it in the body as well.
How do I pass the options as a variable to the controller so that I get list/employees and list/contracts when I list the table data with findAll?

Comment: If you need extra data or to clarify something feel free to ask!

Comment: I think @RequestParam should work in this scenario. And also could you please explain what do you mean by "I'm using it in the body as well"?

Comment: It seems that when you submit the form, url '/list/${tableName}' does not resolve 'tableName' variable. Try to replace ${tableName} for any hardcoded value just to check that the controller is working properly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The full getTables is: `<code>`@RequestMapping(value = "/list/{tableName}", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
 public String getTables(Model m, @PathVariable("tableName") String tableName) {
  Integer idPrepend = spravochnikService.getIdAtSpravName(tableName);
  List<Spravochnik> spravList = spravochnikService.findAll(tableName);
  m.addAttribute("spravList", spravList);
  m.addAttribute("tableName", tableName);
  m.addAttribute("idPrepend", idPrepend);
  return "home";
 }`</code>`

Answer (score 1):

`@RequestParam` is use for query parameter(static values) like: http://localhost:8080/calculation/pow?base=2&ext=4

`@PathVariable` is use for dynamic values like : http://localhost:8080/calculation/sqrt/8

```
@RequestMapping(value="/pow", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public int pow(@RequestParam(value="base") int base1, @RequestParam(value="ext") int ext1){
    int pow = (int) Math.pow(base1, ext1);
    return pow;
}

@RequestMapping("/sqrt/{num}")
public double sqrt(@PathVariable(value="num") int num1){
    double sqrtnum=Math.sqrt(num1);
    return sqrtnum;
}
```

Here is link for more about that [@PathVariable vs @RequestParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable)

To solve Your problem You need to see (like in debug mode) if your method `findAll` is actually returning some data and how You then send this data to the view.

Comment: Thank you! If I'm not adding the ${} and {} things it returns all I need, just the url is just /list

Comment: Also I would recommend to not use method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET }. Just make 2 methods with annotation GetMapping and PostMapping.

Comment: So how to make the form select option appear in the url of list? Maybe not the code, just a hint or piece of advice

Comment: {tableName} will be PathVariable then because it will be dynamic value depends on what You choose in form then use this value in findAll method to get list of Data from {tableName} and return it to view.

Comment: Yes, I used it as a path variable, and if i type the uri manually, that is, /list/employees, it works, but how do I pass the tablename from the form? My jsp seems wrong

Comment: Jsp seems fine for me but i think You don't do anything with the variable name which is option between employees and contracts. Try using @RequestParam for name to see if it contains something.

Comment: Yes it does contain all I need, I can use it freely if i switch my mapping to list without the variable part, I just cant make it part of the displayed uri

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public String getTables(Model model, @RequestParam String tableName) {

Comment: And for jsp <form action="/list" method="post">
    <p>
        <select name="tableName">
            <option value="employees">Employees</option>
            <option value="contracts">Contracts</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

Comment: But then the list will be available with just the /list uri and I'm trying to make it /list/employees lists employees and /list/contracts lists contracts data

Comment: then return in this method: return "redirect:/" + tableName;

Answer (score 0):

Just use the **@RequestParam** annotation.

As described in the documentation:

> You can use the @RequestParam annotation to bind Servlet request parameters (that is, query parameters or form data) to a method argument in a controller. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestparam

The form:

```
<form action="/list">
  <select name="tableName">
    <option value="employees">Employees</option>
    <option value="contracts">Contracts</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getTables(Model m, @RequestParam("tableName") String tableName) {
  //findAll here
  return "home";
}
```

If your request does not have any side-effect on the server (is read only request), good pratice is to use a GET method.

Comment: Thank you! I'm also trying to make the chosen option appear in the mapping, like /list/employees