# POST to a REST service using Ajax is failing

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-boot

I am working with a javascript client that I am trying to use to communicate with a server. I have a Javascript function that is POSTing to a Spring Boot REST service. The service is a simple test service that doesn't do much...

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value="/testservice")
@ResponseBody
public String testPostRequest(@RequestParam String someText)
{
   System.out.println("Reached the counting service! Param value: " + someText);

   if(someText != null)
   {
      ...
      perform some actions
      ...
   }

   return("Success");
}
```

The Javascript I am using to send POST requests to the server is below:

```
var sendWords = function(toSend) {
    var data = { DataList : [toSend] };
    var param = { someText: data };

    $.post("http://localhost:8080/testservice",param,
        function(status,ret) {
          alert("We're back "+status);
    });
};
```

The toSend parameter is just a string containing some text that will be posted to the service. Note that the port for the service was set to 8080 in the server's application.properties file.

When I call the Javascript function and post the string to the service, I get the following log message from the server:

```
2019-07-28 20:00:06.292  WARN 80844 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'someText' is not present]
```

I am doing something wrong, but cannot figure out what it is. I am sending an object that is tagged as the someText string, but it is not being recognized by the server for some reason.

Can someone tell me what I am missing? How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var data = { DataList : [toSend] };
    var param = { someText: data };
Here data is not string.
You may need to stringify it.

var param = { someText: JSON.stringify(data) };

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the value in the `@RequestParam()`, such as `@RequestParam(value="someText", required=true)`.

You could use @PathVariable too. 
This could be helpful:
[@RequestParam vs @PathVariable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable)

Comment: Thanks. While your entry didn't provide the solution, your link did provide very useful information.