# How to get a param from URL Rest Service that is after a question mark (?)

Tags: spring, rest

I have the following String that I receive in my rest service:

.6.75:5050/pretups/C2SReceiver?REQUEST_GATEWAY_CODE=8050122997&REQUEST_GATEWAY_TYPE=EXTGW&LOGIN=CO8050122997_EXTGW&PASSWORD=89b87741ca3f73b0b282ae165bad7501&SOURCE_TYPE=XML&SERVICE_PORT=190

I have the following code:

```
@Controller
public class servicioscontroller {

 @RequestMapping(value = "/pretups/{p1}?{trama}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 @ResponseBody
public String enviarTrama(@PathVariable("p1") String p1,@PathVariable("trama") String trama){

 return p1+trama;


 }
}
```

And im getting this result:

**C2SReceive**

I need also the string after that ?, what im doing wrong or how do I get that? thanks

Comment: should be @RequestParam("trama")

Comment: @Tao Dong I will try that

Comment: @TaoDong Can I use pathvariable and requestparam at the same time? and also whats the difference mate?

Comment: Your requestmapping don't seems right tho.. It might not contain ?  You don't need to specify requestparam in requestmapping, they should be access by requestparam name in this case i.e. REQUEST_GATEWAY_CODE etc.

Comment: You can use both pathvariable and requestparam the same time. In your case you can try String enviarTrama(\@PathVaraible("p1") String p1, \@PathVariable Map<String, String> trama) which should give you all params as a map. A better solution is to implement as @pks suggests

Comment: Yeah it worked by doing like pks suggest, if anyone wanna post an answer with more detailed stuff go ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`@RequestParam`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html):

```java
@Controller
public class servicioscontroller {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/pretups/{p1}", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = ["trama"])
    @ResponseBody
    public String enviarTrama(
        @PathVariable("p1") String p1,
        @RequestParam(name = "trama", required = "true") String trama
    ){
        return p1+trama;
    }
}
```

Note that you have to put request params in the `@RequestMapping`'s `params` attribute instead of the path string.

The difference between `@RequestParam` and `@PathParam` is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13718502/750510).

Comment: Hey mate that looks good elegant way but what does the required does exactly? thanks!

Comment: The required says that this parameter is requred. If you omit it either other handler will be called (if there is any), or you'll get 404.