# I can't use my web application in order to delete Car from list

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Anybody has an idea what's going on? Why I can't delete my Car?

I have the following error in the web page: There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400). Parameter conditions "idCar" not met for actual request parameters:

These code is work if I will write the following address into web browser bar: http://localhost:8080/cars-web/deleteCar?idCar=2"

This is Code from CarGui with adnotation @Controller

```
@GetMapping(value = "/cars-web/deleteCar", params = "idCar")
public String deleteCar(@RequestParam long idCar) {
    carService.deleteCar(idCar);
    return "redirect:/cars-web";
}
```

This is the code from my CarService

```
@Override
public boolean deleteCar(long id) {
    Optional<Car> found = carList.stream().filter(car -> car.getCarId()== id).findFirst();

        if(found.isPresent()) {
            carList.remove(found.get());
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

And here is my code from my web page:

```
<form th:action="@{/cars-web/deleteCar}" th:object="${someId}" method="get">
<p>Id:<select>
    <option th:each="ids : ${readId2}"
            th:value="${ids}" th:text="${ids}"></option>
</select></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Delete Car From List"></p>
```

Additionally my model

```
@GetMapping("/cars-web")
public String getCars(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("carList", carService.getAllCars());
    model.addAttribute("readId", carService.getListId());
    model.addAttribute("readId2", carService.getListId());
    model.addAttribute("addCar", new Car());
    model.addAttribute("color", carService.getAllCarColors());
    model.addAttribute("someId", "");
    return "cars-web";
}
```

Comment: Guessing the equals and hashcode methods are not overridden on your Car object?

Comment: @dopfz what error appears in your log?

Comment: I knew that I missed something to write: I had the following error: There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Parameter conditions "idCar" not met for actual request parameters:

Comment: It seems that the problem is on your js code, you're not sending a Long parameter.

Comment: UNfortunately problem is the same after changing primitive type to object Long.

Comment: Can I have other Controller with RESTful methods in the same project? Why I ask because I have two Controller class. First one is a RESTful controller and other one is Thymeleaf Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
public String deleteCar(@RequestParam long idCar) {
```

To:

```
public String deleteCar(@PathVariable("idCar") long idCar) {
```

and change:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/cars-web/deleteCar", params = "idCar")
```

to:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/cars-web/{idCar}")
```

You can read more about the different between PathVariable and RequestParam [HERE.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable/13718502)

Comment: I have found a solution of my problem. <select name="id">. It's enough in order to make the program works.