# URL-parameters input seems inconsistent

Tags: url, api-design

I have review multiple instructions on URL-parameters which all suggest 2 approaches:

Parameters can follow <kbd>/</kbd> forward slashes or be specified by parameter name and then by parameter value. so either:

```
1)  http://numbersapi.com/42
```

or

```
2)  http://numbersapi.com/random?min=10&max=20
```

For the second one, I provide parameter name and then parameter value by using the?. I also provide multiple parameters using ampersand.

Now I have see the request below which works fine but does not fit into the rules above:

```
 http://numbersapi.com/42?json
```

I understand that the requests sets 42 as a parameter but why is the <kbd>?</kbd> not followed by the parameter name and just by the value. Also the <kbd>?</kbd> seems to be used as an ampersand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax):

> Every HTTP URL conforms to the syntax of a generic URI. The *URI generic syntax* consists of a hierarchical sequence of five *components*:
>
> ```
> URI = scheme:[//authority]path[?query][#fragment]
> ```
>
> where the authority component divides into three *subcomponents*:
>
> ```
> authority = [userinfo@]host[:port]
> ```
>
> This is represented in a syntax diagram as:
>
> [image: Syntax diagram]

As you can see, the `?` ends the `path` part of the URL and starts the `query` part.

The query part is usually a `&`-separated string of `name=value` pairs, but it doesn't have to be, so `json` is a valid value for the `query` part.

Or, as the Wikipedia articles says it:

> - An optional **query** component preceded by a question mark (`?`), containing a query string of non-hierarchical data. Its syntax is not well defined, but by convention is most often a sequence of attribute–value pairs separated by a delimiter.

It is also fairly common for request processors to treat a `name=value` pair that is missing the `=` sign, as if the it was `name=`.

E.g. if you're writing `Servlet` code and call [`servletRequest.getParameter("json")`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter-java.lang.String-), it would return an empty string (`""`) for that last URL in the question.

Comment: Thank you so much Andreas for the elaborate explanation. This is very helpful. So the query part is always preceded by a ? but does not necessarily contain key value pairs but could just contain the value itself. In my example above, the number 42 is thus not a parameter but part of the path, right?

Comment: @Tartaglia That is correct. In Spring, it's known as a `@PathVariable`. See e.g. [@RequestParam vs @PathVariable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13715811/5221149), which shows you can do both at the same time.