# Rest API request path handle spanish text using Apache camel

Tags: spring-boot, rest, apache-camel

Actually  I create rest api using apache camel. Its a Get Call.

Request Path like this -> **users/names/{username}?client={clientId}**

we will try to given username is Spanish text like this -> **users/names/plánia?client=100**

Its throw error like **bad request**

```
{
   "timestamp": "2020-06-17T16:06:25.609+0000",
   "status": 400,
   "error": "Bad Request",
   "message": "Illegal Argument Specified in the Request Headers or Path",
   "path": "/users/names/plánia"
 }
```

Comment: Make sure that you understand `@RequestParam` vs `@PathVariable` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable

Answer (score 1):

A URL is composed from a limited set of characters belonging to the US-ASCII character set. These characters include digits (0-9), letters(A-Z, a-z), and a few special characters.

`á` does not come under US-ASCII. 
You should try URL encoding before firing such GET request.